# How to backup all files in my iphone? including the operating system files

Tags: iphone, backup, ssh

I want to edit some files in my iphone using ifile/ssh like in this information http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/how-to-edit-itunes-apps-ipa-files-to-be-installed-on-unsupported-devices.370037/

is there a way to backup all files in my iphone first? including the operating system files
if its possible, i will use it to restore all files if the iphone crashed later

Comment: How about you take your iPhone Charger and plug the USB into your PC, then move all of the files onto your PC. Next you won't have anything on your iPhone so restore it by downloading your iOS Version.

Comment: but my iphone is already jailbreaked, so i need to restore all the files exactly like right now, if the iphone crashed later. is there apps or tutorial to do this guys, i already try find but cant find it by my self

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think you can still back up your iPhone with iTunes/iCloud even if it is jail broken. If you really want to back up iPhone as much as iPhone data without iTunes/iCloud there are [paid/free third-party methods](http://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-backup-iphone/) to do so.